# Passing a variable as an argument to a function and assigning a new value to it?

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

While trying to learn how to work with JavaScript Promises, I tried implementing a function that would allow the results of an XHR to be assigned to a variable. I know this is probably not exactly the idiomatic way to go about this. Still, it's an interesting if puzzling problem I'm having with it.

The idea is to wrap the XHR in a Promise, and pass that a resolve function which will assign the XHR response to a variable. Here is some code with an explanation following. Everything to test it in the console is here:

```
function getJSON(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status < 400) {
      resolve(xhr.responseText);
      }
     };
  xhr.send();
  });
}

function assignDataTo(target, url, ctx) {
  // Asynchronously assign JSON response to `target` variable
  getJSON(url)
    .then(function(data) {
         ctx.target = JSON.parse(data);
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      }
    );
}

var targetVariable,
    url = "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/resource/n4ma-fj3m.json?$select=*&$limit=5";

assignDataTo(targetVariable, url, window);
valueOf(targetVariable); // Error: undefined
valueOf(window.target); // JSON: xhr.response
```

Adding the context parameter to `assignDataTo` was an attempt to be more specific about the scope of the variable receiving the data. I found that `ctx.target` (or `ctx[target]`) evaluates to `window.target`, rather than substituting the function argument (i.e., `ctx.target == window.targetVariable`) like I'd hoped.

How would I pass a pointer to the actual variable I want to assign, as an argument to the `assignDataTo` function? (Secondarily, any comments on this general strategy of working with promises is welcome.)

Comment: This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 2):

Strings, Booleans and Numbers are passed by value in javascript. You could however wrap `targetVariable` in an object which would be passed by reference.

`ctx.target = JSON.parse(data);` actually just sets a value for the key `target` in the `ctx` object, which would be the `window` object in your case. It has nothing to do with the parameter `target` that you pass in as a parameter to your function.

Also your `assignDataTo()` function runs asynchronously, so calling `valueOf(targetVariable)` is not going to work, since the Promise is probably not going to be resolved yet ie. the result of the XHR has not arrived yet. A better solution would be something like this.

```
function assignDataTo(url) {
  // Return a Promise
  return getJSON(url)
    .then(function(data) {
       //resolve the Promise with this value
       return JSON.parse(data);
     }, function(error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
  );
}

var targetVariable;
//wait for the Promise to be resolved and then assign the variable and do whatever with it
assignDataTo(url).then(function(result) {
  targetVariable = result;
  valueOf(targetVariable);
});
```

Comment: pedant comment: string, boolean and number etc are _not_ objects in JavaScript, they're values.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have explicitly references (or pointers) as in other languages (ex: PHP &$variable), but it uses references when working with objects.

When sending an array (that is also object in JavaScript) to a function, it will get the same reference of the array. That's why any changes made inside the function, will be available outside.

Example:

```
function addEl(arr) { 
  arr.push(3);
}

var ourArray = [1, 2]; // [1, 2]
addEl(ourArray);
console.log(ourArray); // [1, 2, 3]
```

This works fine with Objects, but it is different when it comes to primitive types: string, number or boolean.
When sending a primitive to a function, it creates a copy of it, so it won't change the primitive from outside the function.

Example with primitive:

```
function increment(el) { 
  el += 1;
}

var numb = 1;
increment(numb);
console.log(numb); // 1
```

Same thing in your code:

```
targetVariable
```

is a primitive variable and

```
window
```

is an object.

When writing:

```
ctx.target
```

you actually are adding a new parameter to ctx (reference to window). If you want to change 'targetVariable', in your function you should assign JSON.parse(data) to window.targetVariable:

```
function assignDataTo(url, ctx) {
  // Asynchronously assign JSON response to `target` variable
  getJSON(url)
    .then(function(data) {
       ctx.targetVariable = JSON.parse(data);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
// ...
assignDataTo(url, window);
```